# Issue with PrestaShop plugin

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

After installing the plugin on Presta Shop. The user is able to make successful payment but the orders and sales are not recorded in the PrestaShop back office ..How do I fix this?

`PrestaShop version :-1.6.1.20`
`Rave PrestaShop plugin version :- 1.6x`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the plugin. It has been updated, sales and orders are recorded in the back office.
find the plugin [here](https://github.com/Flutterwave/prestashop-rave-payment-module-1.6x)